# Python client server to send a file Beginner Error

Tags: python, sockets, pydev

I am trying to do simple code to send file from the client to the server after saving in t some data.
I am a beginner so I can't figure where the problem is or what is the missing function or line in my code

The Server :

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
server_socket.listen(0)
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
conn, addr = server_socket.accept()
print ('Got connection from', addr)
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: 
        break
    fileREC=open (data , 'rb')
```

The Client

```
import socket
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(("192.168.1.4", 8000))
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
TextFile= open ("TextFile","w")
TextFile.write("Here is the file")
TextFile.write("Writing data")
TextFile.close()
f=open (TextFile , 'wb')
print ("Writing the file to binart ")
client_socket .send(f)
print ("Data Sent")
```

The Error

```
  ERROR:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tenmay.py", line 5, in <module>
   client_socket.connect(("192.168.1.4", 8000))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
  return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: What have you done to resolve the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the server has 192.168.1.4 ip? Can you ping this address?

Comment: yes I can ping it and send a string but not a text file

Answer (score 1):

Send the contents of the file not the filehandle:

```
f=open ("TextFile", 'rb')
client_socket.send(f.read())
```

The second time the client runs the server is waiting to recv data because the accept() command is outside of the loop.

The client could repeatedly send data from a loop, but not if the program ends and has to be restarted.